# using HiveContext in spark sql throws an exception

Tags: apache-spark-sql, hivecontext, spark-hive

I have to use HiveContext instead of SQLContext because of using some window functions that are available only through HiveContext. I have added the following lines to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and the spark version on the machine that I run the code is also 1.6.0
 However, when I submit my code to spark, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Iface.get_all_functions()Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/api/GetAllFunctionsResponse;
```

and here is the stack trace:

```
   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.getAllFunctions(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:2060)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:105)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.getAllFunctions(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient$SynchronizedHandler.invoke(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:1998)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.getAllFunctions(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:210)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:243)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:512)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.<init>(ClientWrapper.scala:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.metadataHive$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.metadataHive(HiveContext.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anon$2.<init>(HiveContext.scala:459)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.catalog$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:459)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.catalog(HiveContext.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anon$3.<init>(HiveContext.scala:475)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.analyzer$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:475)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.analyzer(HiveContext.scala:474)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.baseRelationToDataFrame(SQLContext.scala:442)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
    at com.cloudera.sparkwordcount.FindServers.main(FindServers.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Has anyone any idea?

Comment: From logs it looks like that Spark 1.6.0 is not built with Hive in it. Try following command to build Spark 1.6.0: `./build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -DskipTests clean package`

Comment: What if it is not possible to rebuild Spark? (e.g. a server from another company)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved similar issue by replacing and explicitly using

```
hive-metastore.jar in my spark-submit command:
--conf /path_to/hive-metastore.jar
```

The jar I was using before the issue occurred was incorrect for another environment.

> The working jar was located in cloudera parcels directory (depending
>   on a distribution), e.g.:
>   /cloudera/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.232957/lib/spark2/jars/hive-metastore-1.1.0-cdh5.12.0.jar

Cheers,
Michał